# How to get the content of a jquery variable to use it in a sql query in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

I'd like to know how can I use a jquery variable in a sql query?

Here is my jquery that is in my php file:

```
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#event_form_field-<?php echo $event_id; ?>').click(function() {

var bradio = jQuery("input[type=radio]:checked").val();

alert(bradio);

}) });</script> <?php
```

I want to use the bradio variable in a sql query (on the Having clause, for example Having answer='$bradio'.

But i don't know how to passe the jquery variable in php.

Can you please explain me how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: as far as I know the only way to pass data from javascript to php is through GET or POST. You'd have to make a call to the same script and pass it bradio as a parameter. But maybe someone else knows a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to pass the variable to a PHP script. That PHP script can also return data to the JavaScript AJAX call, for instance you can output `error` or `success` in your PHP file so the JavaScript code can alert the user as to what happened (in my example this response is saved in the `serverResponse` variable):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#event_form_field-<?php echo $event_id; ?>').click(function() {
        $.get('path/to/server-side.php', { 'bradio' : $("input[type=radio]:checked").val()}, function (serverResponse) {
            //the server request has been made and has come back successfully
        });
    });
});
```

Some documentation:

- `$.get()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I use the variable bradio outside the jquery? I'd like to pass the variable to my php code.

Comment: @user1073001 The second argument of the `$.get()` function is the data that will be sent to the server. In my answer that is: `{ 'bradio' : $("input[type=radio]:checked").val()}`. Which means in your PHP you will be able to access the checked radio input's value as `$_GET['bradio']`. I highly recommend reading the documentation for `$.get()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. How can I know the server path? I'm using the cms wordpress. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1073001 Well you are going to have to FTP up the file so you will know where it is (or if you upload it with the WordPress admin then it will tell you where it is), if you are trying to send the data to a PHP file that is part of the WordPress install then I recommend searching on Google the name of the file to find it's location.